# MVC Action Method with nullable parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes

I am calling a action with the parameter value. But it is not assigning parameter value to action method parameter.

```
    public ActionResult UserDetail(long? userId)
    {

    }
```

> localhost/Admin/UserDetail/10 --> 10 is not passed to userId

But

> localhost/Admin/UserDetail/?userId=10 --> This works

What causes the first url not working? Any help?

Update:

tried this in global.asax still not working

```
 routes.MapRoute("ExistSiteUser",
              "UserDetail/{userId}",
               new
               {
                   controller = "Admin",
                   action = "UserDetail",
                   // nothing optional 
               }
         );
        routes.MapRoute("NewSiteUser",
             "UserDetail",
              new
              {
                  controller = "Admin",
                  action = "UserDetail",
                  userId = UrlParameter.Optional 
              }
        );
```

Comment: by default, mvc routes accommodate 1 route param called id. either add routes to include userId or just use id.

Comment: @DaveA, can you give the answer for adding a new route that accepts `userId` ? I tried that in global.asax but not sure what mistake i have made there

Comment: @Billa Please consider green-checking this answer if it served your purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the parameter name to 'id' instead of 'userid' and then try....it should work then

```
public ActionResult UserDetail(long? id)
{

}
```

Comment: i think you need lower case id

Answer (score 3):

Replace this userID to id :-

```
public ActionResult UserDetail(long? id)
    {

    }
```

Comment: i think you need lower case id

Comment: @Billa Please consider green-checking this answer if it served your purpose.